# How to create context pad in mxgraph?

Tags: javascript, bpmn, mxgraph

I am trying to create a list of example shapes which will be shown when any shapes in canvas is clicked. How do i create this in mxgraph.

i tried using popup menu in mxgraph and tried adding shapes to it.But i am unable to create the popup menu. i am using graph editor examples and want to create popup menu in mxgraph when any shape created is clicked.

```
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id","geApp");
        var graphs = new mxGraph(document.getElementById("geApp"))
        graphs.setTooltips(true);
        new mxRubberband(graphs);
        var parent = graphs.getDefaultParent();
        graphs.popupMenuHandler.autoExpand = true;

                // Installs context menu
            graphs.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod = function(menu, cell, evt)
                {
                    menu.addItem('Item 1', null, function()
                    {
                        alert('Item 1');
                    });

                    menu.addItem('Item 2', null, function()
                    {
                        alert('Item 2');
                    });

                    menu.addSeparator();

                    var submenu1 = menu.addItem('Submenu 1', null, null);

                    menu.addItem('Subitem 1', null, function()
                    {
                        alert('Subitem 1');
                    }, submenu1);
                    menu.addItem('Subitem 1', null, function()
                    {
                        alert('Subitem 2');
                    }, submenu1);
                };
```

I am getting error as

it skips the

```
graphs.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod().
```

I want to create a popup menu or a context pad in mxgraph whenever a shape created on canvas is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The graph does not have createElement() function, instead you should use :

var t = document.createElement('div');

But why are you appending this div to container?

Please write the code in the following way. The return statement is missing in your code

```
graph.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod = function(menu, cell, evt)
{
    return createPopupMenu(menu, cell, evt);
};

function createPopupMenu(menu, cell, evt)
{
  // Your code to add the menu item
}
```

Comment: i Tried tat and even removed the container. but still i cant see the popup menu.

Comment: While execution it skips the popupmenu.factorymethod completely

Comment: plese check above i have edited the question with my latest code tat i have tried

Comment: Please check the above code and let me know if it works for you

Comment: still the same... it skips the function moves to next line.

Comment: Can u show me the console screenshot, once you right click on the shapes which are inside the mxgraph container